# Is it possible to add a request parameter to dojo module requests via dojo's AMD loader

Tags: dojo

Is it possible to modify request urls used by the dojo AMD loader before a request is sent to the server for an AMD module? I would like to append a request parameter with a version number.

The problem we are trying to solve is that we want our javascript files to be cached by the browser unless the application's version is updated. I think we should be able to do that if we can add a version number to the requested URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `paths` config property seems to work for individual modules, and `cacheBust` can be used for all modules. [Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Bxq/4/).

```
<script>
var dojoConfig = {
    paths: {
        // version a single file by using path with version number
        "aa": "mylib-aa.js?v=1.0",
        // standard path, no explicit versioning
        "bb": "mylib-bb"
    },
    // use v=1.0 for ALL loaded modules
    cacheBust: "v=1.0",
    waitSeconds: 10
};
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["aa", "bb"], function () {});
</script>
```

Giving:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/mylib-aa.js?v=1.0.js&v=1.0"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/mylib-bb.js?v=1.0"
```

The hiccup for the `paths` approach is the trailing ".js", but for the purposes of versioning I don't think that's an issue as the URL is still unique in the way you want it to be.

Comment: what about appending the same http params to all requests, regardless of package? Is there a way to configure that?

Comment: Yes, that can be achieved with the `cacheBust` config parameter - https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.8.3/dojo.js#L527.

Comment: Thanks Paul, your answer helps, but an answer to David's question would be idea. If there was a way to do it across all packages, that would be better.

Comment: We are avoiding the cache bust approach because we want to allow the js to be cached unless the version is changed.

Comment: `cacheBust: "v=1.0"` will work. Then `cacheBust: "v=1.1"` when you want to upgrade, etc.

Comment: This is very useful answer, it deserves upvotes but I think that the question that initiated it, also deserves some